# Sending UDP datagrams using QUdpSocket and QDatastream

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qdatastream, qudpsocket

The program is able to send .txt files. But any other filetype gets corrupted. I think it has something to do with the datatypes I store my frames in. Sorry for the long post i just have no idea where my problem might be.

I'm new to QT as well as C++. I HAVE TO use QUdpSocket to send any file over a network to another computer. This computer should then reassemble the datagrams in the correct order and save it as a file. (QFiles have to be broken up in segments with sequence number headers and reassembled according to these numbers). Segments are stored with their sequence number in a QByteArray array.

```
//Setup File
filelocation= opendialog->getOpenFileName(this, "Select File to be sent", "C:/Users/<USER>/Desktop");
SentFile.setFileName(filelocation);
if (!(SentFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))){
    return;
}

//Setup Datastream
SentData.setDevice(&SentFile);
SentData.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);
SentData.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
SentData.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);

//Calculate number of frames to be sent
max_framesize=200;
int length=SentFile.size();
dsize=length/max_framesize+1;
if((length%max_framesize)!=0)
    dsize++;

//Write initial message with dsize and file name
char BeginMessage[max_framesize+16];
char *cfile= new char[filelocation.length()+1];
strcpy(cfile, filelocation.toStdString().c_str());

sprintf(BeginMessage,"%016d%010d%s",0, dsize-1, cfile);
SendArray[0]= BeginMessage;

int i=1;
while(SentData.atEnd()!=true)
    {

    char s[max_framesize+1];

    int len = SentData.readRawData(s, max_framesize);
    for(int n=len; n<=max_framesize;n++)
    {
        s[n]='\0';
    }
    char tempframe[17];
    sprintf(tempframe,"%016d",i);
    tempframe[16]='\0';

    SendArray[i]=s;
    SendArray[i].prepend(tempframe);
    i++;
    }
```

The QByteArray Array is then sent over the qudpsocket

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

for(int l=0; l<dsize; l++)
    {
    QByteArray datagram = SendArray[l];
    socket->writeDatagram(datagram.data(), QHostAddress::Broadcast, 5743);
    }
    ui->lineEdit->clear();
    ui->lineEdit->setFocus();
 }
```

The Reassembly code works as follows

```
void MainWindow::receiveData()
{
while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
{
  FramesReceived++;

    QByteArray datagram;

    datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 senderPort;
    socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                            &sender, &senderPort);

    char temp[datagram.size()];

    strcpy(temp, datagram);

     char cseq_num[17];
         for(int n=0; n<16;n++)
         {
           cseq_num[n]=temp[n];
         }
         cseq_num[16]='\0';
         datagram.remove(0,16);

     int seq_num = atoi(cseq_num);
     if(seq_num==0)
     {
         char size[11];
             for(int n=0; n<10;n++)
             {
               size[n]=temp[n+16];
             }
             size[11]='\0';
          rsize = atoi(size);

        QByteArray   Name=datagram;
         Name.remove(0, 10);

         strcpy(OriginalName,Name.data());
     }
    ReceivedArray[seq_num]= datagram;
    char message[600];

   sprintf(message,"%d of %d Frames Received\nFile name: %s",FramesReceived,rsize, OriginalName);
ui->label->setText(message);
}
}
```

After all frames have been received

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{

filelocation= opendialog->getSaveFileName(this, "Save File");
ReceivedFile.setFileName(filelocation);
if (!(ReceivedFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))){
    return;
}

char snum[27];

    for(int n=0; n<27;n++)
    {
      snum[n]=ReceivedArray[0][n];
    }
    snum[27]='\0';

int len_num = atoi(snum);


ReceivedData.setDevice(&ReceivedFile);
ReceivedData.setByteOrder(QDataStream::BigEndian);
ReceivedData.setFloatingPointPrecision(QDataStream::SinglePrecision);
ReceivedData.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_5);
for(int i=1; i<len_num; i++)
{
ReceivedData.writeRawData(ReceivedArray[i],ReceivedArray[i].length());
}

ReceivedData.writeRawData(ReceivedArray[len_num],ReceivedArray[len_num].length());
ReceivedFile.close();
}
```

Comment: The UDP is not a reliable protocol even for text file, why didn't you use the  QTcpSocket instead?? if you are insisting on using UDP you have to implement your own protocol for reliability.

Comment: I know it is part of the task to do it with UDP and write your own acknowledgment and reassembly code (own protocol). But my program works fine with text. For some reason any other files get corrupted.